# Wrap 'full html' output with CDATA in Service view?

Tags: 7, views, services

I'm using [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) modules. I have created service display view which includes body field(full html type). In the output url view source body is rendering with `&lt;p&gt;` which i want to avoid.
Can anybody help me to wrap body element with `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`.
I tried rewriting field and view template both are not effecting the output.
Sevice view format setting is the following.

> [image: Sevice view format]

The body configuration is the following.

> [image]

I tried adding a global custom field, and wrote [body], which was printing properly, but when I wrap `[body]` field with `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` , nothing is coming in the output.

How do I write `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` in a custom field?

Comment: change format of views field to services raw will work for you.

Comment: format of views field is updated to  services raw, but still when i view page source of output url ,i can see same output with value,safe value ,format etc. but &lt; is still there

Comment: add new service display from that view not page or block

Comment: The view which i created is service display view only. U mean adding one more service display?